# Wordpress portfolio pagination on home page

Tags: plugins, php, ajax

I am new to wordpress i am trying to add pagination to my home page that shows portfolios, example there are total of 80 portfolios when i open my site it automatically shows all 80 portfolios on home page ,is there any way that i can add **pagination** or **load more** kind thing on my home page .how to to do that
have a look at what it is like now [view here](http://members.photoshop-plus.co.uk/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the amount of posts to display in the admin panel under 'Settings > Reading > Blog pages show at most .. posts'.

If you want to style this afterwards, more information here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination
Or a useful plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-paginate/